# How to change text button when click in adapter

Tags: java, android, button, baseadapter

How to change text button when click in adapter
I try it's not work

```
 public void setQuestData(final ViewHoder viewHoder, final int position) {
        viewHoder.btn_select_qq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!profileFeedListModelTwos.get(position).getStatus_select().equalsIgnoreCase("SELECTED")){
                    viewHoder.btn_select_qq.setText("Accepted");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

How to fix it ? and where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not handle the click event inside the adapter class , instead **handle it in the fragment using BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewInteractionListener() or adapter listener of the adapter that you are using.**
2. **Set position as a tag** inside your adapter then use it get the item in your fragment.
3. Make your adapter **extend BaseRecyclerViewAdapter  or adapter that you are using**

**Basic Idea**
adapter = new Adapter(`enter code here` for setting click listener)

**Inside YourAdapter** just set the clickListener to your view

```
viewHoder.btn_select_qq.setOnClickListener(this)
```

**Inside your fragment** handle the action on click

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(),new BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewInteractionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (int) view.getTag();

ItemObject item =adapter .getItem(position);
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.view1:
                        //TODO write logic here
                        break;
                    case R.id.view2:
                    //TODO write logic here
                        break;
                    case R.id.view3:
                      //TODO write logic here
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry I dont understand , I use BaseAdapter and I dont know to set you code